# deploy flask on apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, raspberry-pi

trying to do whats described here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps
and here:http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/#configuring-apache

but no matter what I try I end up with these errors in the apache error log:

```
[Sun Mar 22 12:25:45 2015] [info] [client 192.168.2.10] mod_wsgi (pid=4842, process='', application='192.168.2.32|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/hello_world/hello_world.wsgi'.
[Sun Mar 22 12:25:45 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.10] mod_wsgi (pid=4842): Target WSGI script '/var/www/hello_world/hello_world.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Mar 22 12:25:45 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.10] mod_wsgi (pid=4842): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/hello_world/hello_world.wsgi'.
[Sun Mar 22 12:25:45 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.10] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Mar 22 12:25:45 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.10]   File "/var/www/hello_world/hello_world.wsgi", line 12, in <module>
[Sun Mar 22 12:25:45 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.10]     from hello_world import app as application
[Sun Mar 22 12:25:45 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.10]   File "/var/www/hello_world/hello_world/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Sun Mar 22 12:25:45 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.10]     from flask import Flask
[Sun Mar 22 12:25:45 2015] [error] [client 192.168.2.10] ImportError: No module named flask
```

here's my wsgi file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging

activate_this = '/var/www/hello_world/hello_world/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
exec(open(activate_this).read())


logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/hello_world/")

from hello_world import app as application
application.secret_key = 'bigsecret'
```

and my **init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, I love Digital Ocean!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and my virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName 192.168.2.32
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/hello_world/hello_world.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/hello_world/hello_world/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/hello_world/hello_world/static
                <Directory /var/www/hello_world/hello_world/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel debug
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have everything installed in a venv. when I run **init**.py directly it runs fine

Any suggestions ??

Comment: try `execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))`

Comment: another try `WSGIPythonPath /var/www/hello_world/hello_world/venv/lib/pythonX/site-packages` (Note `x`)

Comment: Do you have Flask installed as a `site-package`? This looks to like a lib path issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may install the wrong version of mod_wsgi.
you should install the version for python3